# where does j save the result of its last operation?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, j

In python's repl, `_` holds the value of the last operation.

Where is the value of the last operation saved in the j repl?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such a thing.

Comment: What IDE are you on? I think that JHS and Jqt have different globals, but I am not sure about the console.